# Can we perform insert on a vector using back()-value index on it?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Recently i came across a scenario where i had to insert values in a vector using a slice of other vector and put it at the back. I tried using vector.back()-value but it did not allow me to do so. Here is the code snippet

```
tempVector.insert(inputs.back()-temp,inputs[loopVar]);
```

And the error shown was

> no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert [with _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list

I tried look for some example like this online could not find much on this. Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong in here? I am new to STL and c++14

Comment: `tempVector.insert(tempVector.end() inputs.end() - temp, inputs.begin()
 + loopVar);` ? (assuming that `inputs.end() - temp <= inputs.begin()
 + loopVar`)

Comment: `insert()` expects an iterator in the 1st parameter.  `back()` returns (a reference to) the last element value, not an iterator to the last element. To get an iterator to the last element, use `end()-1` instead (assuming the `vector` is not empty). Then you can subtract from that iterator as needed.

Answer (score 1):

> ... *insert values in a vector using a slice of other vector and put it at the back...*

**Solution 1:**

There's a [`std::vector::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) overload that has the form:

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

So you can write:

```
  std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  std::vector<int> b = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

  b.insert(b.end(), a.begin() + 2, a.begin() + 5);
```

**Solution 2:**

Use the `std::copy` algorithm with a [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
  std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  std::vector<int> b = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

  std::copy(a.begin() + 2, a.begin() + 5, std::back_inserter(b));
```

**To test it:**

```
  for (auto& x : b)
    std::cout << x << ' ';
```

Will output: `6 7 8 9 10 3 4 5`

Answer (score 0):

The `insert` method accepts an iterator as the first argument (e.g. see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)). To insert an elemt at the back, you could try the following:

```
vec.insert(vec.end(), value);
```